# Subset a list by dynamic lengths efficiently

Tags: r, loops, subset

My data consists of a large list of integers of various lengths and I want to subset each element to a pre-specified length.

An example of my data:

```r
my_list <- list(c(-4L, -2L), c(4L, 6L, 9L, -4L, 10L, 2L, -3L, 8L), c(-1L, 
                                                          1L), c(-4L, -5L, 5L, -2L, 4L, 10L, 7L), c(-2L, 10L, 3L, -3L, 
                                                                                                    8L, -1L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 2L))
```

I know the final lengths beforehand and want to essentially pick the first n numbers of each list element based on those calculated lengths.

Let's say those final lengths are:

```r
sizes <- c(1, 7, 0, 5, 8)
```

This would mean the output should look like:

```r
[[1]]
[1] -4

[[2]]
[1]  4  6  9 -4 10  2 -3

[[3]]
integer(0)

[[4]]
[1] -4 -5  5 -2  4

[[5]]
[1] -2 10  3 -3  8 -1  7  4
```

As my real data consists of > 500k groups, loops are generally too slow and therefore I would prefer a faster solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest code I can think of is to `Map` the data and the sizes, and subset via `head`:

```
my_list2 <- rep(my_list, 1e5)
sizes2 <- rep(sizes, 1e5)

system.time({Map(head, my_list2, sizes2)})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   2.81    0.19    3.00
```

The speed can be improved 4x by using direct subsetting in the same method:

```
system.time(Map(\(l,s) if(s == 0) l[0] else l[1:s], my_list2, sizes2))
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.69    0.00    0.69
```

Directly altering the list in-place via `length<-` with a for loop is quicker again:

```
system.time({
    for(i in seq_along(my_list2)) {
        length(my_list2[[i]]) <- sizes2[i]
    }
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.16    0.02    0.18
```

The loop returns the same result as the `Map` option too:

```
identical(my_list2, Map(head, my_list2, sizes2))
##[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This does produce the correct answer, but is a bit too slow on my actual data. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @NicChr - how fast does it need to be? This code will process a `my_list` of length 500K in about 3 seconds from a quick test.

Comment: Ideally it would need to be in the 1-100ms range, but if it's not possible then I may need to reframe the problem.

Comment: @NicChr - I can get it down to about 0.6 seconds with my edit, if that helps.

Comment: @NicChr - getting close with 250ms with a loop.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get chance tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: That's a nice solution, really cool!

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own C / C++ implementation to get slightly more speed out of it.

Here's one way to do it. Where you have a `0` in your sizes object I'm creating an empty vector, rather than leaving the list element NULL as this aligns with your expected output.

This also has no error checking (index-out-of-range, etc). It assumes all your inputs are sanitised.

```r
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
  
  code = "
  Rcpp::List list_subset(Rcpp::List my_list, Rcpp::IntegerVector sizes) {
    R_xlen_t n = sizes.length();
    R_xlen_t i;
    
    Rcpp::List res(n);
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
      Rcpp::IntegerVector int_vec = Rcpp::Vector< INTSXP >(my_list[i]);
      int end_range = sizes[i];
      if( end_range > 0 ) {
        res[i] = int_vec[ Rcpp::Range(0, end_range - 1 ) ]; 
      } else {
        Rcpp::IntegerVector empty_vec(0);
        res[i] = empty_vec;
      }
    }
    
    return res;
  }
  "
)


## Benchmarking

my_list2 <- rep(my_list, 1e5)
sizes2 <- rep(sizes, 1e5)


loop <- function(list, sizes) {
  
  for(i in seq_along(list)) {
    length(list[[i]]) <- sizes[i]
  }
  return( list )
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  
  rcpp = { list_subset(my_list = my_list2, sizes = sizes2) },
  
  loop = { loop(my_list2, sizes = sizes2) },
  
  times = 5
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
#  rcpp 44.79767 45.13387 49.50189 46.49572  52.65503  58.42717     5
#  loop 67.35541 67.35808 88.13320 77.38955 104.78837 123.77457     5

identical(loop(my_list2, sizes2), list_subset(my_list2, sizes2))
# TRUE
```

Comment: Nice. I suspected Rcpp would be quicker. Interesting that it isn't a dramatic improvement in this instance.

Comment: I think you could get slightly more speed out of it if it were purely written in C, and in a package. But if you're going down that route, you probably want to look at the whole analysis workflow to see if it's worth it.

Comment: That's really cool, worked like a charm too!